# Select variable and count of SQL table in same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

say i had this php script below to select the count of the number of rows true to the query

```
    $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM friend_request WHERE prelim_user_id = ? AND friend_user_id = ?');
    $sth->bindParam(1, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

    $suggestion_friend_request_count = $sth->fetchColumn();
```

Is there anyway to select the count as well as a variable from the table in the same query?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, just use a GROUP BY with the variable you want to include.

Comment: Which variable you want to select and why?

Comment: What does *a variable from the table* mean exactly?

Comment: The variable would just be `request_status` which is just an enum of '0','1','2'

Comment: sorry in variable i meant column name

Comment: And from which row you want this variable?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired results?

Comment: And why do you want it from the same query?

Comment: I want it so i don't have to run the query twice, once to get the count and a second time to get the column data

Comment: if you need columnn data, you don't need count then. Just get your data and then count it

Comment: so you think it might be better to get the data i need from the table and then count it after?

Comment: it is not "better". It is sane.

Comment: sane? you mean its common sense to do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a group by similar to:

```
SELECT column_A, COUNT(*)
FROM friend_request
WHERE prelim_user_id = ? AND friend_user_id = ?
GROUP BY column_A
```

The group by will allow you to count each distinct group of values in column_A

Comment: Ok, to get the returned column_A could i just get the returned column_A with a normal while loop, as if i were doing it without the count?

Comment: What the group by will provide is show distinct values in the the column, and the count tells you how many rows that value appeared in. Other wise, if its just `SELECT column_A FROM ...` will just dump all the rows. It depends what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Along with adding the column to the select part of the statement, you would need to `group by` the column that you want to select in addition to the count.  This will create separate rows for each distinct value in the `group by` column. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) has more detailed information if needed.